# Why won't this Scripting Addition run from a Mail rule?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, applescript

When I access the [satimage.osax scripting addition](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) (which I'm using for its regex capability) from a Mail rule on Snow Leopard, I get errors, but it runs fine in Script Editor. The code below illustrates the problem. The first line executes fine, but the line inside the `tell` block throws an error (below), from the mail rule version, which I had catching the error.

```
set substr to find text "a" in "abcd"

tell application "Mail"
    set substr to find text "a" in "abcd"
end tell
```

[image]

So I tried a workaround: `tell application "Finder" to ...` from within the Mail Rule script, but that then threw a security error.

Comment: Where do you have the plug-in installed?

Comment: Can you access the Satimage library from non-rule script but still in a `tell application "Mail"` block? I'm just thinking that this might a sandboxing feature to prevent overwhelming processes being potentially kicked off without you knowing until it's too late.

Comment: No, it fails inside a `tell application "Mail"` block as well - if it's a sandboxing thing (which it seemed like to me, as well) what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a sandboxing problem - it's a 32/64 bit problem. Mail is a 64-bit application in Snow Leopard, and as of right now, [Satimage.osax](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) is a 32-bit addition. So for the time being, I set Mail to **Open in 32-bit mode** (see picture). I arrived at this conclusion after reading a [MacScripter forum post](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30258). I'd still love to hear another workaround, in case Satimage stays a 32-bit addition.
[image]

Comment: @sakra - did you run it from inside a Tell application "Mail" block? That was the problem posed.

Comment: I would imagine that in order for this to work as intended you will need to wait until both Satimage and Mail are both the same bit modes. That, or write your own extension that is 64-bit (or get someone to write for you).

Comment: Your AppleScript returns:
{matchPos:0, matchLen:1, matchResult:"a"}
Lipo returns the following architectures for satimage: ppc7400 i386 x86_64

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have different results - I started off with the most recent version (build 360). Are you on Snow Leopard as well? And do you have Mail starting up in 32-bit mode already? I only see the error when Mail is opened in 64-bit mode (Snow Leopard's default).

Answer (score 0):

Given this is more than likely a sandboxing issue the only workaround I can think of is to place the calculations in a script or script application(1) outside of Mail (2), call *that* from Mail, and handle a returned result.

(1) Whichever works best for this situation.

(2) Your User Scripts folder would be a good place for this

Comment: Arghh, I tried putting the "find text" statement in a handler in an external script, and it fixes it for a `tell application "Mail"` block, but it still fails in a Mail rule. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm out of ideas. It sounds almost like a bug now.