# Get part of string in Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I try to make a applescript that read files in a folder and takes only part of the filename. The files would look like this: the.name.of.a.tv.show.s01e01

I could search for s01 but then i have to make a rule for every season that can come.

Is there some way to look for s--e-- and then take the part of the filename before that?

Comment: Sounds like you need http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php - unless your goal is actually to reinvent the wheel using a limited scripting language. If that's the case, look at these string functions for applescript: http://aurelio.net/doc/as4pp.html

Comment: As far as i can see that is for Windows only. And i do not want to rename them, i need to check the titles of the shows.

Comment: If you have operating system restrictions you should add those, and any other relevant tags to your question.

Comment: @Alain it's tagged osx and by the way you could suppose that if he's using applescript he needs a solution which works on OSX.

---- Anyway, I don't see any other way around shell script. You can use sed with appleScript and do regex to get what you want : [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat)

Comment: @Aleks I just edited it to add the OSX tag.

Comment: In addition to using the shell's `sed` or `grep`, you can also search with regular expressions within AppleScript directly, by installing the [Satimage scripting additions](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/text/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set xxx to "the.name.of.a.tv.show.s01e01 etc etc"
set yyy to (do shell script "echo " & xxx & " | sed 's/.s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9].*//'")
return yyy
```

Incorporating your previous question:

```
set seasonList to {}
repeat with aShow in listOfShows
set aShow to aShow as string
set end of seasonList to (do shell script "echo " & aShow & " | sed 's/.s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9].*//'")
end repeat
return seasonList
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is good to see an example. But, i don't know so much about regular expressions, how can i get the part before s01e01 instead of s01e01, which is the values returning now?

Comment: I feel like i'm asking very much now, but how can make it remove everything after s01e01 also?

Comment: Thanks :) Regular expressions are hard to understand.