# Removing part of string in Applescript

Tags: shell, applescript

So I have a string but I only want it after a certain part. I know that you would optimally do this in shell so I tried, but my limited shell knowledge didn't bring me far. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073428/get-part-of-string-in-applescript) tries to do a similar thing but not exactly what I need.

```
set theString to "hello/world"
do shell script "echo " & theString & "???"
return theString --the output should be hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no shell script needed. Get the position of the slash in the string and return the substring from the beginning to the position - 1

```
set theString to "hello/world"
set slashIndex to offset of "/" in theString
return text 1 thru (slashIndex - 1) of theString
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```
set theString to "hello/world"
set firstWord to 1st word of theString

return firstWord
```

**OR**

If there are any other characters and including “/“ in `theString` , the following should take care of that.

```
set theString to "hello/world"

set firstWord to 1st word of (do shell script "echo " & ¬
    quoted form of theString & " | sed -E 's@[^[:alpha:]]{1,}@ @'")

return firstWord
```

Comment: While in this specific use case it works, nonetheless, it is not as reliable as the mentioned presented in the accepted answer. Yes, this also works with some other characters, but it would fail with  `"hello'world"`, `"hello.world"`, `"hello_world"` or an integer between, e.g. `"hello1world"`

Comment: Just to be clear, note that my original comment was in reference to your original answer, not the now edited **OR** part.

Comment: What's with the extra `quote`'s in the `do shell script` _command_, are they even needed? Also, as currently written the `sed -E 's@[^a-zA-Z]@ @g'` is doing nothing and is just being pipped into the `tr` _command_. In other words, the `tr` _command_ is returning `" hello world  sed  E s   a zA Z    g "` from the `do shell script` _command_. If the `do shell script` _command_ is properly formed you shouldn't need both `sed` and `tr` as either one by itself should return the desired results. That said, is even practical to use `do shell script` _command_ here? I can see good reasons not to.

Comment: In other words, the example in the OP `"hello/world"` is just a place holder, the real target is `/` and the `sed` and `tr` _commands_ as currently written exclude everything but _alpha characters_.  Using _offset of_ or **AppleScript's** _text item delimiters_ is really the better ways to go here.

Comment: It turns out all of my “workarounds” with the extra inserted `quote`s and the pipe to `tr` could have been avoided had I not forgotten to place the `|` before the `sed` command in my original OR addition

Comment: RE: "It turns out all of my “workarounds” with the extra inserted `quote`s and the pipe to `tr` could have been avoided had I not forgotten to place the` |` before the `sed` command in my original OR addition" --  Yes and that is part of why I said what I did in my third comment. Yeah, I could have just told you were missing a `|`, but wanted you to figure it out on your own base on the obvious clue about what `tr` was returning in the `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: Anyway IMO there still is an inherent flaw in your `do shell script` _command_ in that it excludes all non-alpha characters and thus if there are wanted non-alpha characters in what's being parsed then therein is the issue. That said, as long as one knows what it's doing, it can have its uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **AppleScript's** *text item delimiters*:

```
set theString to "hello/world"

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
set theString to first text item of theString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

do shell script "echo " & theString's quoted form & "???"
```

**Returns:**

```
hello???
```

However, `return theString` after processing with **AppleScript's** *text item delimiters* will just return `hello` in this use case.

---

Note the use of `'s quoted form` in `theString's quoted form` with the *variable* in the `do shell script` *command*, as you should always *quote* what's being passed to the *shell*. You can also use this form: `quoted form of theString`

As you can see the *offset of* method presented in one of the other answers is more straight forward, however I've added this as an answer so you know what your other options are.