# AppleScript to append date to file

Tags: macos, applescript, rename, automator

I was recently able to make a drag and drop script in Automator that allowed me to zip and name a file and then automatically apply the date (DDMMYY) but now it's defaulting to (DDMMYYYY) and I can't change it. I've googled for a solution and nothing works since this needs to be at the end of the file name.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or does anyone have an actual script that can help me? Everything I've found only works if the date is at the start of the file name, not at the end (but before the extension).

[image: Workflow from Automator]

Comment: I tried posting an image of my workflow but I'm not allowed. I'm also very new to this, so I don't have any code, just drag and drop from Automator. It let me post a link, so that's up). I'm on Big Sur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this AppleScript inside a **Run AppleScript** action, it renames the archive inserting the date before the file extension

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set thePath to POSIX path of (item 1 of input)
    set currentDate to do shell script "date +%d%m%y"
    set newPath to text 1 thru -5 of thePath & "_" & currentDate & ".zip"
    do shell script "mv " & quoted form of thePath & space & quoted form of newPath
    return {POSIX file newPath as alias}
end run
```

Comment: @Steven Cheak, Please note that as currently coded, it has the potential to overwrite an existing _file_ without warning. To ensure a _file_ is not overwritten, change `"mv "` to: `"mv -n "`

Comment: Interesting.  While this contains a lot of AppleScript syntax, it’s all padding except for the line _`set newPath to …`_  What made you choose to wrap what is essentially a shell script inside an AppleScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code I can't guess how you name your files, but the way to get DDMMYY is to use shell with the `do shell script` command:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to (choose file)
    set theName to name of theFile
    set name of theFile to theName & "_" & (do shell script "date +%d%m%y") & ".xxx"
end tell
```

This doesn't get rid of the file extension of the original file. For that to work you would have to use something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to (choose file)
    set theName to name of theFile
    set periodIndex to offset of "." in theName
    set theName to text 1 thru (periodIndex - 1) of theName
    set name of theFile to theName & "_" & (do shell script "date +%d%m%y") & ".xxx"
end tell
```

<sub>The code responsible for removing the file extension comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795052/removing-part-of-string-in-applescript).</sub>

You can add punctuation how you like by putting the desired symbols before the next `%`. So `date +%d.%m.%y` is possible and improves readability.

Comment: Sorry. Not very good at this. So our standard file naming convention is filename_DDMMYY.xxx

Comment: `file (choose file)` – even if it worked – is syntactical wrong. `choose file` returns an alias specifier so the keyword `file` is a double reference. Remove `file`.

Comment: @vadian I'm in the process of rewriting the script to fit the comment that OP left.

Comment: What about if the file is named _`Paris.LaCroix.men.zip`_ ?

Comment: @CJK I‘ve rarely seen someone put multiple periods in a single filenames. If you know of a way to get around that, feel free to edit my answer

Comment: Multiple periods are extremely common.  And you, yourself, stated that `%d.%m.%y` was a possible way to improve readability.  You are using _Finder_ to rename the file, so a good thing to do would be to read its scripting dictionary to see if there are any other properties of a file other than its `name` that you can make use of to cater for every eventuality.