# Separate ending number of a string into variable with Applescript

Tags: numbers, applescript

I was wondering if it's possible to detect a number on the end of a random string. For example in this string: "localfile/random/1" I'd like to split this string so one variable would be the number on the end of a string, and second variable would be the rest of path. I couldn't google anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use shell for that purpose. See idea in [this][1] post


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat

Answer (score 1):

If you can just split the strings around the last slash:

```
set x to "localfile/random/1"
set text item delimiters to "/"
{(text items 1 thru -2 of x) as text, last text item of x}
```

Both of these only work if the strings always end with numbers:

```
on test(x)
    set c to count of x
    repeat with i from 1 to c
        if item (c - i) of x is not in items of "0123456789" then
            return {text 1 thru (c - i) of x, text (c - i + 1) thru -1 of x}
        end if
    end repeat
end test
test("localfile/random/1")

do shell script "sed -E $'s/([0-9]*)$/\\\\\\n\\\\1/' <<< " & quoted form of "localfile/random/1"
set {x, y} to paragraphs of result
```

Answer (score 1):

This will let you split the string without having to specify the last character before the number string:

```
set myString to "localfile/random/13451"
set delimiter to "||"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, delimiter}
set myItems to text items of (do shell script "sed -E 's/([0-9]+$)/" & delimiter & "\\1/' <<< " & quoted form of myString)
set text item delimiters to TID
return myItems
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
set s to "blah4"
set l to (get last character of s)
if "1234567890" contains l then log "yes"
```