# Search folder for files with matching prefix and perform action in applescript

Tags: applescript

I have 10s of thousands of PDF files and I'd like to find ones that match certain characteristics and perform an action (merge into a PDF)

For example, I have files like:

```
filegroup1_abc.pdf
filegroup2_xyz.pdf
filegroup3_qrs.pdf
filegroup3_lmn.pdf
```

I'd like to find every file that has the same prefix, "filegroup1" and merge them into one PDF, then find the next match (filegroup2), then the next, etc...

So in my above example the last two would be merged as a new PDF since they have "Filegroup3" prefix.

I have found a script to merge PDFs using applescript; so my main question is how to search through the folder, find those files, then perform an action on them.  However the pattern of "filetype1" is not known, so the script would first need to check every file and compare when the first X number of characters match in the filename.  In this case it's the first 22 characters are identical and indicate a relationship between the files.

Also, I'm trying to do this in applescript but it might be easier to do with another method.

Comment: It looks like applescript supports regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat

Comment: Thanks @eebbesen, I will need that; but maybe my problem is more basic, how do I find every file where the first X characters match and perform an action on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--choose working folder
set ff to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)
try
    --returns files matching names as return-delimited text, filter to list of "paragraphs"
    -- using built-in AS object text awareness
```

**[EDIT]**

```
    --OLD; incorrect:
    --set allABCs to every paragraph of (do shell script "cd " & ff & ";" & "ls filegroup*_qrs.pdf")

    -- new and improved:

    set allABCs to every paragraph of (do shell script "cd " & ff & ";" & "ls filegroup1_???.pdf")

    --that matches only 3-character strings. The following
    -- matches any number of characters between _ and .pdf:

    --set allABCs to every paragraph of (do shell script "cd " & ff & ";" & "ls filegroup1_*.pdf")

on error--it's in a try because if you mistakedly look for files that aren't there,
    --    it will return an error. As an aside, doing 'ls' and getting folders
    --    returns extra empty strings -- just a cautionary note that probably doesn't matter here
    return {}
end try
```

--and one more caution which you may not need -- you may need to sort results to order the files correctly, if that matters to you

Comment: Thank you @CRGreen, that is getting me closer, but I need to know when the wildcard matches, not just produce a list.  So in `ls filegroup*_qrs.pdf` whenever the wildcards are the same in the returned list I need to perform an action on those matched files.

Comment: ok, @nocabt i've updated the code. but 'when the wildcard matches' shouldn't matter. You should be able to produce each list of files to work on for each group. You assemble the group algorithmically or 1 at a time, whatever suits you.