# How can a sequence of regular expressions (with replacements and extractions) be executed in order on a single body of text?

Tags: regex, sequence

What is a good way to run a sequence of regular expressions on a body of text?
Both regex for finding and replacing patterns

I’ve spent days searching for it without success. I would be happy with an answer that was nothing more than a Google search in the right direction.

Comment: Jeff, you are looking for `sed -e 'first expression' -e 'next expression' -e 'and so on...'` (**note** at first blush, `sed` may look overwhelming, but you can digest it slowly)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you are right!  sprague44’s answer lead me to this (since I prefer mac) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat  I agree I will have to take the time to learn it, but I guess that’s the fun part.

Comment: Yep, both `sed` and `awk` are daunting at first, but they are different blades to the swiss-army knife of text handling. (both are available on Linux/max)

Comment: Yeah I had read some on sed and awk, and they seem really powerful. But being generally coding-illiterate, when I had trouble with the flags in sed I was overwhelmed with the terminology and found Python. I do have a Mac so that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot has changed since I asked the question, and for those are looking for an answer, the solution can be done in Ruby, Python, Javascript, Perl, and pretty much any language that supports Regex. I still don't know of a great online or GUI program for it.

Awhile ago, I created a simple GUI for it in Python. Here's how to install it.

1. **Install Python: 2.7**
   (https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. **Install the Regex Python Module:**
   If on Mac, open the Terminal app. If on Windows, open Command Prompt. Then 
   type `pip install regex` and let it install
3. **Download this Python file:** 
   [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz6cPkDulveZZjdfT255MTNhZjA)
4. **Run the file:** Open the file with Python Launcher 2.7

The program should be pretty self-explanatory, but I created a help document [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AWSjcD4WCnsYHfvb8pJimdY66xkwL8mdUc6LzI96dFI/edit) if anyone has any trouble.

An example of an in-code alternative would be to create a Python file (TextFile.py) and have the following code in it.

```
import regex as re

#input your file path
location_ = **YourFilePath**
f = open(location_,'r+')
text_ = f.read()
f.close() 

# input your regular expressions
text_ = re.sub(r'Your_Regex_Find' ,'Your_Regex_Replace' ,text_)
text_ = re.sub(r'Your_Regex_Find2','Your_Regex_Replace2',text_)

print text_
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements, I would approach it with `sed` similar to:

```
sed -e 's/\n\w/#*4#/g' -e 's/\n/[enter]/g' -e 's/[#][*]4[#]/START/g'
```

As a quick example of the successive application of the regex, consider:

```
echo "this is absolutely absent minded bs" | \
sed -e 's/ab/#*4#/g' -e 's/b/[enter]/g' -e 's/[#][*]4[#]/START/g'
```

Output:

```
this is STARTsolutely STARTsent minded [enter]s
```

It will match your regex of `newline` and `word` in an identical fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a simple script to do something like this.

If you are on windows .bat files, if you are on Linux (or have access to something like Cygwin) bash (.sh)

The find and replace functions should be searchable once you choose a scripting language

Comment: so essentially use a .bat file to execute multiple lines of commands such as the commands listed on this page? http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php

Comment: Yes, if you use .bat.  I would strongly recommend installing Cygwin (it's free) and using bash functions such as sed, much more powerful and I also found bash much easier to understand

Comment: I knew about bash files, but it took me some time to actually find some tools for bash to execute regular expressions. I didn't really know what scripting languages were, but I later found perl and attempted sed, but had trouble learning some of the more-complex flags and commands for them