# Check if string follows pattern

Tags: applescript

I have a string in applescript and I want to see if it follows the pattern "%i,%i,%i,%i". is there some way I can check if this is true?

something like

if str follows pattern "%i,%i,%i,%i" then ...

Comment: I don't see what the "pattern" is. If I don't see, how can the computer see? Give examples of strings that "follow the pattern".

Comment: For the pattern "%i,%i,%i,%i" an example string could be "4,12,56,2". Something that doesn't conform would be like "a2,5d,s2,6k". (%i means integer, %f is float, %lf is long float, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there something akin to regEx in applescript, and if not, what's the alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat)

Answer (score 0):

```
Is4integers("4, 12, 56, 2") --> true
Is4integers("4, 12.3, 56, 2") --> false
Is4integers("1, 3") --> false
Is4integers("5, a3") --> false
Is4integers("true, 3, 2, 1") --> false

on Is4integers(aString)
    set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
    set tempList to text items of aString
    if (count of tempList) ≠ 4 then return false
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    repeat with temp in tempList
        try
            if class of (temp as number) is not integer then return false
        on error
            return false
        end try
    end repeat
    return true
end Is4integers
```

Answer (score -1):

Uno

Check out this SO [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat) that utilizes Applescripts ability to perform system level tasks.

It would be ideal if Applescript supported regex proper but the solution noted works just fine.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, you should flag it instead of posting an answer linking to the original question.