# How do I write this Objective-C code into AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I want to implement this Objective-C example to be used in AppleScript but I don't know how to do it.

```
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
 }
```

Here's what I've got so far and I don't know how to proceed

```
set theString to "hello world"
set theString2 to "\\w+"

set firstMatch to (regex's firstMatchInString:theString options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:(count theString)}) as list  -- do I need to coerce to list?
-- below is obviously wrong
if firstMatch is not missing value then 
    set matchRange = current application's NSRange's range
end if
```

Comment: Use `NSAppleScript`?

Comment: I don't know how to use that either, I'm using applescript in Script Edtor

Comment: Try to understand what the Objective-C code is doing and do the same in AppleScript. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there something akin to regEx in applescript, and if not, what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997828/is-there-something-akin-to-regex-in-applescript-and-if-not-whats-the-alternat)

Comment: No that answer uses command line programs like sed, which is what I already tried before. Also tried via ruby.  Unfortunately they don't work very well for me that's why I'm looking for an alternative so I'm trying it out via Objective-C.  I'm stuck because I don't know how to speak in AppleScript-Objective C.

Comment: Ruby also has fairly robust regular expressions, if there is something more complicated that you are wanting to do, you might mention it.

Comment: Why do need Applescript, isn't the Objective-C code working for you?

Comment: I updated my answer just now.

Comment: I wrote a set of [AppleScript libraries](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) some years ago that wrap these ObjC APIs behind nice familiar AppleScript terminology. You may find that helpful.

Comment: @red_menace my issue with ruby is that I need to call it via command line. Revisiting the code, I realized it breaks because I use sed to pipe the result to remove the double quotes in the result, and sed breaks when passed with Unicode characters. I can stick with ruby, but I'm also happy to learn another way to do it, via Objective-C.

Comment: @Cristik, I'm using AS because it's the main language I'm using right now, and Objective-C is just a side quest that I need, to alleviate the limitation of AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exists only one range (with index=0) in this case. So, do not request for range at index > 0

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set searchString to "hello world"
set regexString to "\\w+"

set anNSString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:searchString
set stringLength to anNSString's |length|()
set theRegex to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:0 |error|:(missing value)

set match to theRegex's firstMatchInString:anNSString options:0 range:{0, stringLength}

if match is not missing value then
    set matchRange to match's numberOfRanges()
    --> 1, so exists only one range, with index=0
    set matchRange to match's rangeAtIndex:0
end if

set firstMatchString to text ((matchRange's location) + 1) thru ((matchRange's location) + (matchRange's |length|)) of searchString
```

Comment: The regex here is just matching the first word, so your comparison fails since the match range will never equal the search string length.

Comment: I want to find the first word that matched the pattern, which is "Hello" in the example.

Comment: @red_menace: Don't get in where your knowledge is limited. In such cases, it is better to remain silent than to give the wrong advice.

Comment: Not sure what is up with the attitude, but your earlier script would only return true if the match had the same length as the string, while the regex was matching words.  Your edited script now pays attention to the match result.

Comment: @red_menace: I was able to refine the script after the OP clarified what it is trying to achieve. In his last comment. The previous script also worked, but it was intended for a different purpose. You did not understand anything about it, but you commented it as non-working. That's why I asked you not to interfere.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis thank you for the answer, tbh I was hoping for this exact answer and Imagined it would be easy for someone who already knows both AS and Objectiive-C, but difficult for me who has no experience with Obj-C. It's my mistake that I wasn't clear on the requirement, when I made the assumption that the function `firstMatchInString` would return the value that I thought it would without elaborating with example. I disagree on how you responded to red_menace, it came out arrogant because his/her advice is not wrong, in fact s/he read my mind. It's a simple misunderstanding.